# Can I make the webcam take a picture when an incorrect password is entered?

Tags: software-recommendation, scripts, security, startup, webcam

I am using a laptop . I was thinking to have a support in my Ubuntu machine.  When an incorrect password is entered, a picture is taken later revealing who has been trying to gain access.

I have searched around and the only thing I have found is stuff to do this on Macs. Is It possible to write a script for Ubuntu to do same .

If possible then what is a script or Software to make this happen.

Comment: A picture on the lightdm login screen or something like a password protected screensaver (Basically before login in or after login in)?

Comment: Yes picture on lightdm login screen when user put incorrect password.

Comment: "Proper" solution via PAM [on the Ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9827947&postcount=10). Okay I will post this as an answer. :)

Comment: Alternatively, install a third-party application such as [Prey](http://preyproject.com/). It doesn't do exactly as you ask, but it specialises in protecting and recovering your computer in the case of theft.

Comment: Don't forget to mention the use of the webcam taking a picture in case you 're in a sensitive/protected environment.

Comment: Why are you starting a bounty, it appears you already have an excellent answer. If that answer doesn't meet what you want it's best to explain why.

Comment: @seth did you try this on some steps system is getting hanged .

Comment: You should leave a comment on the answer then.

Answer (score 65):

<sup>Based on [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9827947&postcount=10) on the Ubuntuforums by [BkkBonanza](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=550406).</sup>

This is an approach using PAM and will work for all failed login attempts. Using SSH, a virtual terminal or via the regular login screen, it doesn't matter as everything is handled by PAM in the end.

1. Install [ffmpeg [image: Install ffmpeg]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ffmpeg), we're going to use this as a command line way of grabbing the webcam images. **Update**: ffmpeg is removed when you upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04. We can use avconv in place of ffmpeg in the below script. No need to install anything separately.
2. Create a small script somewhere, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/grabpicture` with the following content:

   ```
    #!/bin/bash
    ts=`date +%s`
    ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s vga -i /dev/video0 -vframes 3 /tmp/vid-$ts.%01d.jpg
    exit 0  #important - has to exit with status 0
   ```

   Change the `/dev/video0` with the actual video device of your webcam and choose a path where the pictures are being saved - I just choose `/tmp`.
   In the newer version of Ubuntu use `avconv` instead of `ffmpeg` (`sudo apt-get install libav-tools`).
3. Make it executable, e.g. `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/grabpicture`.
4. Test it, by just calling it: `/usr/local/bin/grabpicture`. Check if you see files appearing in `/tmp/vid....jpg`.
5. Configure PAM to call this on every failed attempt.

   Note: do this carefully - if this fails you'll not be able to gain access to your system again in a regular way.

   1. Open a terminal window with root access (`sudo -i`) and leave it open - just in case you screw up in the next steps.
   2. Open `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` in your favourite editor, e.g. by doing `gksudo gedit /etc/pam.d/common-auth`. Keep in mind for the following steps that order of lines in this file matters.
   3. Locate the line below. By default there's one line *before* the one with `pam_deny.so`. On my 12.04 system it looks like this:

      ```
        auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
      ```
   4. In this line change the `success=1` to `success=2` to have it skip our script on success. **This is an important step** If you failed this step see below how to recover (***).
   5. Right below there, add a new one to call the actual script:

      ```
        auth    [default=ignore]                pam_exec.so seteuid /usr/local/bin/grabpicture
      ```
   6. Save and close the file. No need to restart anything.
6. Test it.

   1. In a new terminal window, as regular user, try `su -l username` to log in as another user with username `username` (change with an actual one of course). Deliberately enter the wrong password. Check if this result in a new picture.
   2. The same as above, but now enter the correct password. Check if you log in and it doesn't result in a picture being taken.
7. If the tests have succeeded you can log out from your DE (Unity/KDE/...) and you should see the same when entering a wrong password from the login screen.

(***) How to recover the system if you messed with /etc/pam.d/common-auth file:

- Reboot the computer
- At grub boot press "e" to edit
- Add

> init=/bin/sh

to the line starting by "linux"

Mount the system with write access

> mount -o remount,rw /

Edit the file and fix

> vi /etc/pam.d/common-auth

Comment: That's clever. Two questions: (1) Shouldn't you use a folder other than `/tmp`, because `/tmp` is cleared every time you reboot? (2) How do you tell what your actual video device is?

Comment: This works but I wanted to add 3 things. (1) We can use /var/tmp which is not cleared on reboot. (2) Tread with this solution carefully as it is possible to get stuck in infinite loop of "low graphics mode" and/or "checking battery state", as I was. (3) If you get stuck, reboot and get into recovery mode (press left-shift); select "failsafe graphics mode" and see if / is mounted RW; now drop to root shell; cd to /etc/pam.d; chmod common-auth to RW, edit using nano to remove the line added to call the grabpicture script; save; exit; reboot.

Comment: I figured out why my PC got stuck. Steps 5.3 to 5.5 in the answer need to be adjusted according to what lines the common-auth file has. My common-auth also had another line for pam_winbind.so between the lines having pam_unix.so and pam_deny.so. Basically the auth lines on "success" need to skip the capture script as well as the pam_deny.so line.

Comment: I Also trying to same concept but the above mentioned answer not working it takes me low graphics error,neither it takes any image nor any error message for wrong attempt.
..
What to do next. (gertvdijk)

Comment: @gertvdijk: It would be great if you could also add the **Anti-theft Mechanism** suggested by the users in that thread as a Bonus/Addendum to this Answer.

Comment: should maybe be updated to use avconv or opencv as opposed to the now deprecated ffmpeg

Comment: @hbdgaf : Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't Open CV for proccessing images and not capturing them? Maybe it can capture them too but it won't be needed unless you need to proccess it. For e.g. do motion or face detection.

Comment: opencv isn't necessary, but it has a really simple api for frame grabbing.  much easier to use a simple api and write a five line script than to read the source of guvcview and wrap your head around the uvc api.

Comment: I upgraded my 13.10 installation to 14.04 and noticed that ffmpeg was removed. My webcam grab script (based on this answer) wouldn't work anymore! Solution? Just replaced ffmpeg with avconv and it worked like charm.

Comment: @Sri Feel free to edit (improve) my answer to use the ffmpeg successor. That's how this site works. :)

Comment: If I forgot the step 5.4, and I can't log as SU anymore, how can I fix it?

Comment: @rodi Boot up with live/recovery image and change the file on your installation.

Comment: ffmpeg hasn't been deprecated, here's a blog post about it: http://blog.pkh.me/p/13-the-ffmpeg-libav-situation.html

Comment: @Sri - I have a smilar script to yours I think, but I can't work out where to put the extra line now - do you have an example?

auth [success=2 default=ignore] pam_unix.so nullok_secure\n
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_winbind.so krb5_auth krb5_ccache_type=FILE cached_login try_first_pass \n
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds \n
auth requisite   pam_deny.so \n
(comments don't seem to allow newlines, replace \n with a newline)

Comment: If you have trouble with ffmpeg you can use `fswebcam`,
`fswebcam -r 640x480 --jpeg 60 -D 1 /tmp/shot-$ts.%01d.jpg`

Comment: @gertvdijk , this is a great answer and it worked like a charm for me. Just for a supplement to this question, is it possible to run the same script `grabpicture` when someone logs in the guest account.

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation

One way that enables you to run a command when an incorrect password is entered, is to make use of the Authorization Log.

> **Authorization Log**
>
> The Authorization Log tracks usage of authorization systems, the
> mechanisms for authorizing users which prompt for user passwords, such
> as the Pluggable Authentication Module (PAM) system, the sudo command,
> remote logins to sshd and so on. The Authorization Log file may be
> accessed at `/var/log/auth.log`. This log is useful for learning about
> user logins and usage of the sudo command.
>
> [More here on LinuxLogFiles](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles)

On a failed login attempt, a record will be appended to the `/var/log/auth.log` file and the last line will contain something like:

```
pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): authentication failure;
```

If you constantly monitor the file for modification and check if the last line contains the keyword **failure** with for example `grep failure` then you know a failed login attempt has just occurred and you can run whatever command you want based on this action.

---

## Solution

> Change `echo "failed login"` in the scripts below to the command you
> wish to run upon a failed login.

You can monitor the last line of the `/var/log/auth.log` file with a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
       sleep 1


        if (( $(tail -1 /var/log/auth.log | grep failure | wc -l) == 1))

        then

                echo "failed login"

                # Your command here

        fi

done
```

Or even better, you can install `inotify-tools` and use `inotifywait` to monitor the file instead of the `sleep 1` and the script will be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while inotifywait -q -e modify /var/log/auth.log >/dev/null

do

        if (( $(tail -1 /var/log/auth.log | grep failure | wc -l) == 1))

        then

                echo "failed login"

                # Your command here

        fi


done
```

`inotify-tools` can be installed with the following command:

```
sudo apt install inotify-tools
```

---

## Implementation

To run this solution as a system service, please follow these steps:

- Copy and paste the script code above ( *without `echo "failed login"` as I added this line for debugging purposes only* ) into a file in your home directory and name it `TakePicture.sh` and save the file.
- Make the shell script file **executable** by running the following command in the terminal:

```
chmod +x ~/TakePicture.sh
```

- Create and edit a custom systemd service to run the shell script at boot by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/TakePicture.service
```

- Copy and paste the following code into the editor, replace `USERNAME` with **your username** and save it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then press <kbd>Y</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> :

```
[Unit]
Description=Take Picture

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/USERNAME/TakePicture.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- Start the service by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo systemctl start TakePicture
```

- Enable the service by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo systemctl enable TakePicture
```

---

**Notice**:

The authorization Log will contain all sorts of failed logins or authentications ( ie. GDM, SSH, terminal user authentication, sudo, ... etc. ).

If your aim is just to activate the script when an actual physical login happens ( ie. someone is sitting infront of your computer, using your keyboard and looking at your screen ), then you need to change the above if statement to be like this:

```
if (( $(tail -1 /var/log/auth.log | grep gdm | grep failure | wc -l) == 1))
```

if **GDM** is your login manager. This way the script will only be triggered if an actual failed physical login happens.

Comment: This Solved my problem with some configuration. I solved the service stuck problem by changing Type like `Type=Simple` instead of oneshot. I used the first posts code in `# Your command here` area without exit 0. Here is my files: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402101/make-the-webcam-take-a-picture-when-an-incorrect-password-is-entered-or-wrong-f

Comment: For newbies (like me): Don't forget to open `/tmp` (or where your pictures are in) folder in root mode with `sudo nautilus` command to delete pictures