# Lock-screen to take a picture after incorrect password

Tags: password, lock-screen, lock, unlock

Is there a way to modify the lock screen to show a custom message and/or take a picture (/w the webcam) when incorrect password was typed in? (Like it was shown in the movie Goodbye World)

(And does anyone know where are the files used by the lockscreen? - I mean codes)

Comment: I think its already asked http://askubuntu.com/questions/253189/can-i-make-the-webcam-take-a-picture-when-an-incorrect-password-is-entered

Comment: Please checkout this answer on your first question:
http://askubuntu.com/a/253200/284553