# How to take a photo from webcam when someone attempt to open a password protected PDF?

Tags: scripts, password, security, pdf, webcam

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and want to add a security feature to my system. From this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253189/can-i-make-the-webcam-take-a-picture-when-an-incorrect-password-is-entered), I came to know how to take picture when an incorrect password entered in login screen, using the following script,

```
#!/bin/bash
ts=`date +%s`
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s vga -i /dev/video0 -vframes 3 /tmp/vid-$ts.%01d.jpg
exit 0  #important - has to exit with status 0
```

After making it executable, I am able to take pictures from my webcam with this script.

I have some confidential PDF documents which are password protected. Now I want to do the same thing again. I want to take picture, if someone attempts to open those files with incorrect password. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this with [Incron](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/trigger-commands-on-file-or-directory-changes-with-incron/).

Install Incron `sudo apt-get install incron` and configure it with `incrontab -e` similar to adding regular cron jobs.

eg. `/path/to/pdf/files/ IN_ACCESS /path/to/script.sh` save and voila.

> NOTE: Do not do any action from within a incron job in a directory
>   that you monitor to avoid loops. Example: When you monitor the /tmp
>   directory for changes and each change triggers a script that writes a
>   log file in /tmp, this will cause a loop and might bring your system
>   to high load or even crash it. - Quoted from https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/trigger-commands-on-file-or-directory-changes-with-incron/