# Send SMS / alerts to my iPhone when wrong password is entered on login screen

Tags: iphone, notify-send, sms

I hope this question haven’t asked till today.
My question is that there is a chance that I can connect the main login screen (that one when you’re lock your computer / once you’re turning you’re computer on with the GUI and the sliding animation) to my iPhone and when someone is entering the wrong password this will send my phone SMS Or some kind of alert?

Thanks :)

Comment: You could always look into `logwatch` and have it send you an email for invalid logins, etc.  Most SMS messages from a computer can be done the same as emails.  Look into your carrier, for example, T-Mobile is `phonenumber@tmomail.net`

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1309353

Comment: @Terrance Hey, could you explain more?
I've looked it up and for some reason I have not found any article or something that would be helpful.
And I'm from Israel, so T-Mobile is not operating in my countty.

Comment: I'm not familiar with mobile carriers from Israel.  One way to find what your carrier SMS email might be is to send a text to your email address and see where it comes from.  You would also need to have some sort of email transport like Gmail SMTP that is free so that you can send emails command line from your system.